# How do I convert a text file into a dictionary and print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My file is formatted into three columns of numbers:

```
2    12345    1.12345
1    54321    1.54321
3    12345    1.12345
```

I would like to have Python use the first two columns as keys and use the third column as the values. The file is large, meaning that I can't format it by hand. So how do I have Python automatically convert my large file into a dictionary?

Here is my code:

```
with open ('file name.txt' 'r') as f:
    rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in f ) 
    d = { row[0]:row[:3] for row in rows}
    print(d)
```

The output prints the numbers diagonally all over the place. How do I format it properly?

Comment: It looks like the first line of the sample would create a key of `"2"` and a value of `['2', '12345', '1.12345']`. Is that what you intend? As far as printing it, sending a dictionary to the standard `print()` function doesn't automatically format it, so you'll have to decide how you want to print it and then implement it.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the desired output?

Comment: [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) may be  able to help some with the formatting.

Comment: Dude you need to put example output. How're you gonna access this dictionary? @TigerhawkT3 already suggested a solution that you can process sequentially. Otherwise you have to create dict-of-dict - and define on what keys you want to access what values.

Comment: Yes at @TigerhawkT3 that is exactly what intend or atleast what my professor wants. Perhaps there is a more simpler way of going about this? Please let me know. The dict-of-dict idea seems promising. Can you guys elaborate?

Comment: So, you want the first column as the key, and a `list` of all three columns as the value?

Comment: I would like the first two columns as the key and the third as the value. Is that format possible? Does it make sense? @TigerhawkT3

Comment: "The first two columns as the key and the third as the value" is ___mutually exclusive___ from the "key of `"2"` and a value of `['2', '12345', '1.12345']`" that is the exact intent of what your professor wants. Please decide what you want.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this...? @Aditya

Answer (score 0):

You should try -

```
import pprint
d = {}
with open ('file name.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split('\t')
        if len(row) == 3:
            d[(row[0], row[1])] = row[2]
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(d)
```

Comment: That won't print the dictionary any more neatly than what the OP has (and I'm not certain it's the dictionary structure they want).

Comment: True, but it does fix the logical issues the OP had in his code, atleast according to his requirements

Comment: I think using pprint is the answer for his question. That formats the dictionary and prints it **properly** on the screen.

Comment: Apparently this results in "IndexError=list index out of range". What do suppose I do?

Answer (score 0):

Banana, you're close.

1. You need a comma separating the arguments of `open`.
2. You want to assign the third member of `row`, i.e. `row[2]`.
3. You need to decide how to group the first two members of row into a hashable key. Making a tuple out of them, i.e. `(row[0],row[1])` works.
4. Print the dictionary line by line.

Try:

```
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in f ) 
    d = { (row[0],row[1]):row[2] for row in rows}
for key in d.keys():
    print key,d[key]
```

Comment: I suspect issue 1 was a copy-paste error, since if they had it like that in their program I think they'd get a traceback saying that `'filename.txtr` doesn't exist.

Comment: This approach, by the way, includes the newline character '\n' as the final character of each dictionary value. To avoid this, use `strip()`, either in `rows = ( line.strip().split('\t') for line in f)` or `d = { (row[0],row[1]):row[2].strip() for row in rows}`. Nice dictionary comprehension, though.

Comment: Can you explain why do I keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range?" Does it have to do with my file. If so, what is wrong? @rjonnal

Comment: It may be because one of the rows in your file has just two values, but I can't reproduce the error without your data file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your slicing is wrong.You can get the first tow column with `line[:2]` and 3rd with `line[2]`.

Also you don't need to create your rows in a separated data structure you can use unpacking operation and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function within a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) :

```
with open ('ex.txt') as f:
      d={tuple(i):j.strip() for *i,j in map(lambda line:line.split('\t'),f)}

print(d)
```

result :

```
{('2', '12345'): '1.12345', ('3', '12345'): '1.12345', ('1', '54321'): '1.54321'}
```

Note that as `*i` is a list and lists are unhashable objects you can not use it as your dictionary key so you can convert it to `tuple`.

And if you want to preserve the order you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open ('ex.txt') as f:
      d=OrderedDict({tuple(i):j.strip() for *i,j in map(lambda line:line.split('\t'),f)})

print(d)
OrderedDict([(('2', '12345'), '1.12345'), (('1', '54321'), '1.54321'), (('3', '12345'), '1.12345')])
```

Comment: Can you help me? Your output is my desired output. But can you elaborate on your explanation?

Comment: @Banana0101 What part is ambiguous?

Comment: I inserted parts of your example above and got punctuation marks in the output @Kasra

Comment: @Banana0101 sorry i didn't get what you mean? I said what part of the code you didn't understand?

Comment: I am new to this. If this makes any sense, I can't completely grasp how to incorporate my code into the examples you've given me above. @kasra

Comment: @Banana0101 I added the links of `dict comprehension` and `map` function it a simple code ;) don't worry pls read the links and if you have any question ask me here ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want the keys to layout. Regardless, you should use the csv module, using the `'\t'` as your delimiter.

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as file:
    tsvfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    d = { "{},{}".format(row[0], row[1]): row[2] for row in tsvfile }
    print(d)
```

Prints out:
    {'3,12345': '1.12345', '1,54321': '1.54321', '2,12345': '1.12345'}

Alternatively, you have this:

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    tsvfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    d = {}
    for row in tsvfile:
        d[row[0]] = row[2]
        d[row[1]] = row[2]
    print(d)
```

Prints out:

```
{'54321': '1.54321', '3': '1.12345', '1': '1.54321', '12345': '1.12345', '2': '1.12345'}
```